# populating datagridview with list of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a List that contains a series of transaction objects.  What I'm trying to do is to display these transaction objects in a Datagridview control on loading a form, basically the Datagridview should represent something of a transaction register to display the data for each of the transaction objects in the list.

I must admit to a lack of experience when it comes to using Datagridviews and I'm having some difficulty with understanding what I need to do here.

My question is, how do I go about getting the details of each of the objects in the list to display in the Datagridview?

Here is my code.

First the transaction class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    // Class properties
    private decimal amount;
    private string type;
    private decimal balance;
    private string date;
    private string transNum;
    private string description;

    // Constructor to create transaction object with values set.
    public Transaction(decimal amount, string type, decimal currBal, string date, string num, string descrip)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.type = type;
        this.balance = currBal;
        this.date = date;
        this.transNum = num;
        this.description = descrip;
    }

    // Get and Set accessors to allow manipulation of values.
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return amount;
        }
        set
        {
            amount = value;
        }
    }
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            type = value;
        }
    }
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return balance;
        }
        set
        {
            balance = value;
        }
    }
    public string Date
    {
        get
        {
            return date;
        }
        set
        {
            date = value;
        }
    }
    public string TransNum
    {
        get
        {
            return transNum;
        }
        set
        {
            transNum = value;
        }
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal addCredit(decimal balance, decimal credit)
    {
        decimal newBalance;
        newBalance = balance + credit;
        return newBalance;
    }

    public decimal subtractDebit(decimal balance, decimal debit)
    {
        decimal newBalance;
        newBalance = balance - debit;
        return newBalance;
    }
    }
}
```

Now the code for the "Register" form:

```
    public partial class Register : Form
{
    List<Transaction> tranList = new List<Transaction>();

    public Register(List<Transaction> List)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.tranList = List;
    }

    private void Register_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //regView represents the Datagridview that I'm trying to work with
        regView.AutoSize = true;
        regView.DataSource = tranList;
        regView.Rows.Add(tranList[0]);
    }
}
```

And here's the output I get.
[image: Register output]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's really two high level approaches to this.

1) Add the manually created rows directly to the `DataGridView`.  In this case, you have to manually update/remove them as things change.  This approach is "ok" if you don't intend to alter/change the content of the display after you initialize it.  It becomes untenable if you do.

To add it directly, you need to create a `DataGridViewRow`, and populate it with the individual values, and then add the `DataGridViewRow` to the `DataGridView.Rows`.

2) Data bind the DGV.  There's many articles about databinding to a `DataGridView`.  In some cases, it's easier to just add your data to a `DataTable`, and then extract a `DataView` from that, and bind the `DataGridView` to the `DataView`.  Other people find it easier to directly bind to a collection.

CodeProject has a decent article to get you started down that path, but a quick Google search will yield many other articles.

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: I had considered data binding as it appears to be the least kludgy solution since it accounts for any changes to the data source.

Edit: I hit enter too quickly.  I was trying to say that I wasn't totally sure about data binding as I've not really done it previously.  I'll take a look at the link you provided, thanks.

Comment: It's a bit complicated at first when you're not familiar with it, but it becomes easier with time and practice (though it can still offer you many frustrating moments).  The situation you have above seems like it should be a simple example to get started with, so good luck.  Feel free to come back with more specific questions if you come across them.

Comment: I ended up using databinding, thank you for the guidance it was quite helpful.  You saved me a ton of grief on this.

Answer (score 6):

use as DGV:

```
DataGridView groupListDataGridView;
```

column:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn groupListNameColumn;
```

column setup should be like this:

```
groupListNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "name";
```

use this property, else all columns will be added.

```
groupListDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

populate like this:

```
private void populateGroupList() {
    groupListDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    formattedGroupList = new SortableBindingList<DataGridGroupObject>();
    foreach (GroupObject go in StartUp.GroupList) {
        DataGridGroupObject dggo = new DataGridGroupObject();
        dggo.id = go.Id;
        dggo.name = go.Name;
        formattedGroupList.Add(dggo);
    }
    groupListDataGridView.DataSource = formattedGroupList;
    groupListDataGridView.Invalidate();
}
```

and model:

```
public class DataGridGroupObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }      //this will be match id column
    public string name { get; set; } // this will be match name column
}
```

Comment: What is SortableBindingList<>() ?

Answer (score 5):

Simply add `using System.Linq;` at the top. Then you can do this:

```
//This will create a custom datasource for the DataGridView.
var transactionsDataSource = tranList.Select(x => new
{
        Amount = x.amount,
        Type = x.type,
        Balance = x.balance,
        Date = x.date,
        TransNum = x.transNum
        Description = x.description
}).ToList();

//This will assign the datasource. All the columns you listed will show up, and every row
//of data in the list will populate into the DataGridView.
regView.DataSource = transactionsDataSource;
```