# JSON.NET "System.OutOfMemoryException" when deserializing into a DataSet

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Very new to C# and JSON. I have been struggling with this problem for about a day and can't figure it out.

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) states both JSON strings are valid.

Trying to deserialize the following

```
{"items":[{"id":"1122267","quantity":"1","bundle":"1"}],"seconds_ago":"1"}
```

throws the exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

If I try

```
{"items":[{"id":"1122267","quantity":"1","bundle":"1"}]}
```

it works.

I'm reading the JSON string from a textbox and then deserializing using the following

```
string json = textBox1.Text;
DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of JSON.NET? Sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: Does `{"seconds_ago":"1", "items":[{"id":"1122267","quantity":"1","bundle":"1"}]}` work? And what about just `{"seconds_ago":"1"}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx), but after playing around with it a bit, I think I've found the reason. According to the documentation:

> The DataSet consists of a **collection** of DataTable objects

Because a DataSet is a collection of objects, you can **only deserialize a collection** (array) into it. So,

```
{"items":[{"id":"1122267","quantity":"1","bundle":"1"}],"seconds_ago":"1"}
```

will not work, because it contains one collection (of `items`) and one property (`seconds_ago`). On the other hand,

```
{"items":[{"id":"1122267","quantity":"1","bundle":"1"}]}
```

works, because it only contains one collection.

Therefore, if you really want to deserialize your json string into a DataSet, you should do this instead:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "items":[{"id":"1122267","quantity":"1","bundle":"1"}],
            "seconds_ago":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

You should really consider [deserializing into a C# object](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeObject.htm) though, which in my opinion is less complicated and easier to handle:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public string seconds_ago { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string bundle { get; set; }
}

RootObject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Deserializing into a C# object seems to work. But im having a tough time looking at the contents. For example `Console.WriteLine(RootObject.seconds_ago);` fails. Idealy i would like to show the data in a datagridview. Using my original method i could just bind the datatable to the datagridview using `dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;`. I assume i will have to loop and write to the grid? Any examples would be most useful. Thanks

Comment: @Tiago How does it fail? Did your original json string contain a value for `seconds_ago`? If `seconds_ago` is a string and your json data did not contain such a value, `RootObject.seconds_ago` will return null.

Comment: I receive 'Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.RootObject.seconds_ago.get'`. I'm using line 13 from [http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DeserializeObject.htm] just suited to my example. I have tried other variations which produce the same error above. Thanks

Comment: @Tiago You are trying to access `seconds_ago` from the class `RootObject`. That is wrong. You should access it with the initialized object/instance of the class (`deserializedObject` in my example). Look closely at the documentation from JSON.NET. It uses `account.Email`, which is an instance of the `Account` class, and not `Account.Email`. Note the case. You probably should get started with a C# tutorial/walkthrough, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx), before going any further. It will help immensely :)

Comment: @Tiago As for binding an object to a DataGridView, that is an entirely different question. You may refer to [Populating DataGridView with list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258468) and [How does one bind a complex object to a DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5955188). There's also an [official walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you could try. If those don't help, you could ask a new question.

Comment: I tried `deserializedObject.items` originally but it didn't give me data just stated something like system.collection.generic.list originally i brushed it off but after your reply gave me the hint. I was able to use `dataGridView1.DataSource = deserializedObject.items;` to populate the datagridview. I very much appreciate you taking the time to reply. I will defiantly look at the provided tutorial/walkthrough.

Comment: @Tiago You are welcome. Definitely go through a C# tutorial first to understand the basics of the language and object-oriented programming. If your problem has been solved, kindly consider marking this as an answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score -1):

The [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) class does not have a property `seconds_ago` or `items`. So therefore

```
DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
```

Will never work because you cannot convert that particular json string to a `DataSet`

Comment: You're assuming he's using the built in DataSet.