# Binding List of object to Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having trouble binding a `List<Person>` to a `DataGridView`:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, bool likesbacon)
    {
        Name = name;
        LikesBacon = likesbacon;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public bool LikesBacon { get; set; }
}
```

The `DataGridView` has 2 columns, a `TextBoxColumn` for Name and a `CheckBoxColumn` for LikesBacon. The `DataPropertyName` is correctly set and the `DataGridView` is created as expected.

```
public MyForm(List<Person> persons)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgv.DataSource = persons;
}
```

But when I click on the `CheckBox` nothing happens (the readonly property of the dgv is set to false). When I debug step by step I found that whenever the mouse hovers a cell of the `DataGridView` the debugger steps into that property in a loop, as long as the mouse pointer is above the cell.

As a result I can't change a Person's properties through the dgv. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258468/populating-datagridview-with-list-of-objects

Comment: Could you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)? Otherwise it's hard do say what's going on. Maybe `LikesBacon` is a readonly property in your real code? Maybe some eventhandler are doing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the `ReadOnly` property of the columns to false I was able to make it work. :facepalm: