# c# windows forms SQL table update

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a common interface to automatically fill the form with sql table details and then write back the edits from the form to sql table.

The following code helps me to write data to a datagrid view

```
    private SqlTable sqltbl = new SqlTable();
    private ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

    public DataTable GetDataTable(string qry)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
        if (rs.State == 1) { rs.Close(); }
        rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;
        rs.Open(qry, Conn1);
        adapter.Fill(SqlTbl, rs);
        return SqlTbl;
    }

    public void MapControlsWithData(DataGridView dg,string qry)
    {
        try
        {
            dg.DataSource = sqltbl.GetDataTable(qry);
        }
        catch(Exception E) { }
    }
```

Here SqlTable is my very own class designed to handle SQL interactions. It uses ADODB Recordsets and Connections.

I'm trying with the below code to write back data from datagrid to sql with no success

```
   public void UpdateDataFromControls(DataGridView dg, string qry)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rs.State == 1) { rs.Close(); }
            rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;
            rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic;
            rs.Open(qry, sqltbl.GetSqlConnection());
            rs.MoveFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i< dg.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<dg.Rows[i].Cells.Count;j++)
                {
                    rs.Fields[j].Value = dg.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                }
                rs.MoveNext();                
            }

            rs.Update();
            rs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception E) { }
    }
```

Any suggestions or simpler ways to handle this..??

Edit -  It seems that the backend datasource I'm referring to is view that involves multiple table joins. However, I was able to do a simple edit to one of its columns like the below

```
update [vw_createshipment] Set  ShipMentID = 'AA' where ShipmentID = 'SomeShipmentID'
```

When I display the details of vw_createshipment to the datagride using the above code, how do it replicate the above update operation..??

Comment: `no success` is not a clear problem statement or question.  The fact that you are using empty catch blocks hides any and all error message NET might report and makes the problem  a Mystery

Comment: no success means it neither shows an error nor updates the records in the back end.. I'm trying to achieve a common interface that would automatically take any random form and map it with its backend.

Comment: Why are you using ADODB?

Comment: @LarsTech Why shouldn't I...???

Comment: @TabAlleman It doesn't show me any errors but it won't update the backend table also.

Comment: It doesnt show errors because you are suppressing them.  Dont so that.

Comment: DataAdapters handle CRUD operations for you. You do not need to do so much work, you just need [to know how to use them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you for your response. It was good to know that, however my idea to develop a common framework where I would be able to pass a datasource and control/form and data mapping to the backend sql is automatically handled. I was able to do the retrieval of data however I'm unable to handle update part.

Comment: Are you passing SQL statements?  How do you pass parameters?  Without parameters, your code is subject to sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: `catch (Exception E) { }`: this is seldom (mabye never) a good idea. I call it "the carpet pattern": if something went wrong, put the dust under the carpet and keep going as anything happened. Even if what happened was "the program failed to save that very important data you think you have saved"

Comment: @LarsTech This is simply a test layer that I'm building to develop a uniform interface that would help me to connect any frontend with its appropriate backend. The actual code (with  parameter handling) isn't the point of discussion here.

Comment: @GianPaolo Please read my updated post.. Thanks It does throw an exception that not all the fields are updatable however when I try to update the underlying view separately then I'm able to edit the individual columns. I'm trying to create a common interface that would help me to connect the front end with the backend

Comment: That's why I offered it as a comment and not as an answer.  I can see where you are going with this and it's not good.  Make sure you use parameters.  Not showing us "actual code" is why you are getting so many comments because we can see the mistakes.  Put your disposable objects into using blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @LarsTech...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own adapter, use something like Dapper.net https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

You can bind the query results and update/insert statements to an object model that you define for your view.

Adding a link to another relevant answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16258547/317855